# ArrayList и AppendAllLines C#

Tags: c#, arraylist

Здравствуйте!

У меня вот такая проблема: когда я пытаюсь сделать `AppendAllLines` чтоб проверить и сохранить остаток Proxy, он кричит что для `ArrayList` так использовать нельзя.

Вот сам код: `File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\Остаток Proxy.txt", Source);`

Код ArrayList `public static ArrayList Source = new ArrayList();`

Скрин ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне быть в данной ситуации? Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Судя по всему `ArrayList` не реализует `IEnumerable<String>`. А вторым аргументом (там где у Вас `Source`) должна быть переменная типа `IEnumerable<String>` или производным от него. Вместо `ArrayList` используйте List<string>, например.

Comment: Тогда мне придется переписывать половину кода, надо как то решить проблему с ArrayList. List<string> я уже пробовал, всё работает, но опять же надо будет всё переделывать.

Comment: public static ArrayList Source = new ArrayList(); - Вот сам ArrayList.

Comment: Хорошо, всё отредактировал.

Comment: Используйте `List<string>` вместо `ArrayList`.

Comment: Если я буду использовать List<string> то мне придется переписывать почти весь код, а его там мама не горюй, по этому к сожалению это не подходит :(

Comment: @user199587, а никто не сказал, что будет легко, хотя возможно хватит простой замены по всему тексту `ArrayList`=>`List<string>`

Comment: @Grundy главное, чтоб потом ничего не отвалилось, что работало с `ArrayList` и не работает с `List` =)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, у них единственное ощутимое отличие это то что `ArrayList` не типизирован, фактически он полностью соответствует `List<object>`

Comment: @Grundy да, но `ICloneable`........ =)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, сомневаюсь, что там вызывается `Clone` где-то, в любом случае легко обходится тем-же Select, либо `CopyTo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как `ArrayList` не реализует generic-интерфейс `IEnumerable<T>`, его нельзя использовать в данной функции. В идеале стоит все переписать с использованием `List<T>`, так как `ArrayList` остался с тех времен, когда в c# еще не было generics.

Но, если нет возможности переписать, можно использовать функцию [`Cast<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx), которая вернет `IEnumerable<T>`

```
File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\Остаток Proxy.txt", Source.Cast<string>())
```

Comment: Всё работает, большое спасибо :)

Comment: @user199587: Тогда не забудьте принять ответ (зелёная галка слева).